# Compile Angular directive from dynamic html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't seem to get this done: I have HTML that is compiled from a ng-repeat, and I'd like to compile the result of that as well. How would I go about that?

I have a dataset containing chunks of text, that have been given a display type. This type is set as the span class. Most types are just triggering CSS rules (for example, comment-style boxes, see screenshot), but others should invoke a directive. 
For example, the chunk containing 'named Nicodemus, ' is of type-hidden. I have a directive that collapses the chunk and inserts a little button to expand it.

Code:

```
<span class="chunk type-{{chunk.type}}" ng-repeat="chunk in verse.chunks">{{chunk.text}}</span>
```

Results in something like

```
<span class="chunk type-hidden">named Nicodemus, </span>
```

If the second would be my source html, it would compile the typeHidden directive just fine. I guess I need to find a way to make angular compile a second time. I can't seem to get it done using $compile (though I guess I don't really understand how that works).

Hope you can help!

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?     Angular will "compile" instructions within an ng-repeat automatically, there's normally no need to explicitly tell it to recurse down to lower levels.   Perhaps if you told us something about what your 'typeA' directive is attempting to do, it would be clearer what you're asking?

Comment: Nothing fancy really. It hides content and adds a little button to make it visible again. It just seems like it doesn't recognise type-a as something that needs to be compiled as a directive.

Comment: Just adding a class `type-a` doesn't automatically make it a directive. You would, in fact, need to compile. But can you explain why you need this dynamic directive here? Can you not use a generic directive that behaves differently depending on its type? To avoid an XY question, can you explain (in the body of the question) what you are trying to accomplish? There could be a more nature way to do so

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I've updated the question. Hope it helps!

Comment: Compiling markup to some other markup and then compiling that resulting markup to still another markup is perfectly doable. However, your statement that "If the second would be my source html, it would compile the typeHidden directive just fine." doesn't sound right to me. The syntax in your second HTML snippet does not make Angular recognize a directive, does it?

Comment: It actually does: you can set the 'restrict' parameter to 'C', which means it will recognise the class name as the directive's trigger.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IdfHvvD7N0MGmkx9QHTo?p=preview) to show how you can get a directive to compile an element and then again.

The code for the lazy:

```
angular
    .module('App')
    .directive('compileTwice', compileTwiceFactory);

function compileTwiceFactory($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',   // Whatever you want
        terminal: true,   // Angular should not keep compiling the element
                          // by itself after encountering this directive!
        compile: compile, // Instead, we tell Angular how to compile the rest of the element
        priority: 1001,   // This directive should get compiled before the others, obviously
    };

    function compile(element, attrs) {
        element.removeAttr('compile-twice');
        element.removeAttr('data-compile-twice');

        return function postLink(scope, _element, _attrs) {
            var compiledTwice = $compile($compile(_element)(scope)[0])(scope)[0];
            // do something with compiledTwice
        };
    }

}
```

**edit:** And obviously you can generalize that to compile an arbitrary number of times that you could specify like this:

```
<div compile-n-times="420"></div>
```

**edit:** The plunker doesn't seem to work under Firefox?

Comment: Looks promising but I can't seem to get it to work, probably because my element is an ng-repeat element. $compile(_element)(scope)[0] returns <!-- ngRepeat: chunk in verse.chunks --> instead of the element HTML

Comment: In your plunker, see what happens when using <div compile-twice number-of-times="0" ng-repeat="boo in ['foo','bar']">abcdef</div>

Comment: @Jurgen Oh, that's because angular directives compile to a comment + the actual compiled element. If you inspect the markup of a page that uses angular, you will see those `<!-- ng-if="..." -->` and `<!-- ng-repeat="..." -->` comments everywhere (except maybe if there's an option to disable them?). So yeah, instead of doing `[0]`, which works when directives behave like you would expect them to and just output the compiled element, you should look for the actual element you need in the array, most certainly by tag name. Easy.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually been able to fix this with a workaround. Not as elegant, but it works if I nest my directive within the ngrepeat and hardcode the name, making it visible using ng-if.

```
<!-- special type hidden -->
      <span ng-if="chunk.type=='hidden'">
        <span class="type-hidden">
          {{chunk.text}}
        </span>
      </span>
```